# List elements in mathrm

Tags: matplotlib, tex

In a for loop, is there a way to include a list element in a title or legend in math mode? The closest I've come to a decent result is with something like this snippet:

```
galaxies=[a,b,c,d,e]
ax = pylab.gca()
for i in range(0,5):
 ax.plot(...)
 ax.set_title(galaxies[i]+'$\mathrm{Histogram}$')
 pl.savefig(...)
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way and do it all in the mathrm part? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to just put `galaxies[i]` inside the _\mathrm_ section of the string?  `ax.set_title('$\mathrm{' + galaxies[i] + ' Histogram}$')`  Keep in mind the `set_title()` is just taking a string as a parameter.

Comment: Since it a a loop, what I want is for the first graph's title to be "A Histogram", the second one "B Histogram" etc. I haven't been able to do that by including galaxies[i] or str(galaxies[i]) in the mathrm section... not a huge deal but I wanted to know if I was missing something obvious.

Comment: The code above calls `set_title()` five times with different strings on the same axes.  Maybe you intend to assign it to different axes?

Comment: That code generates 5 different plots. Sorry, I put in a tiny part of the code in the interest of conciseness but I see it impairs understanding. Edited